# "Missing closing parenthesis" SQL

Tags: sql, mariadb, create-table

keep getting an error on the line where I put my values in, it specifically appears on the "15" of "15 Water Road", same line as VALUES. The error states:

"Syntax Error: Missing closing parenthesis".

Also when I try run it on XAMPP I get:

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Water Rd, 0412345678, 750, 3), (2, Smith, 2, 14 Water Rd, 0412345679, 400, 4),"

Extremely new to DB's and SQL, any help would be much appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE Customer_info (
    CustomerID int,
    LastName varchar(50),
    Username int,
    Address varchar(777),
    PhoneNumber int,
    TotalSpent int,
    OrdersCompleted int
    );

INSERT INTO Customer_info (CustomerID, LastName, Username, Address, PhoneNumber, TotalSpent, OrdersCompleted)
VALUES (1, Mason, 1, 15 Water Rd, 0412345678, 750, 3), (2, Smith, 2, 14 Water Rd, 0412345679, 400, 4),
    (3, Lens, 3, 1 Water rd, 0412345671, 700, 7), (4, Marks, 4, 5 Fire Rd, 0412345672, 100, 1),
    (5, Barr, 5, 19 Fire Rd, 0412345673, 500, 1), (6, Blok, 6, 21 Fire Rd, 0412345674, 1000, 10),
    (7, Pume, 7, 21 Water Rd, 0412345675, 1000, 2), (8, Po, 8, 77 Earth Rd, 0412345676, 1000, 4),
    (9, Adid, 9, 20 Earth Rd, 0412345677, 2, 200), (10, Lew, 10, 6 Earth Rd, 0412345679, 250, 1),
    (11, Chia, 11, 1 Earth Rd, 0412345681, 150, 1), (12, Barrett, 12, 11 Wind Rd, 0412345682, 450, 9),
    (13, James, 13, 9 Wind Rd, 0412345683, 250, 10), (14, Foop, 14, 2 Window St, 0412345684, 200, 10),
    (15, Watch, 15, 8 Window St, 0412345685, 1200, 1), (16, Irving, 16, 11 Window St, 0412345686, 1400, 2),
    (17, Jones, 17, 22 Window St, 0412345687, 1600, 2);
```

Comment: None of your strings are enclosed in quotes. `15 Water Rd` should be `'15 Water Rd'`

Comment: Well, for a start SQL string literals are enclosed in `'` marks.  And with all due respect, if you don't know that, then you need more than a StackOverflow answer or two before you start writing SQL.  Do yourself a favor: take a step back and read up on the language.

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/string-literals/

Comment: @JacobH Oh I see, so everything that has the "varchar" data type has to be inverted commas 'varchar string'

Answer (score 1):

You should enclose the non-numeric values with (single) quotation marks.

The error here is slightly cryptic, but what's going on is that when the DB engine tries to parse what you're inserting, it doesn't know how these characters should be used - for example, whether the commas are part of the string or not (remember, it doesn't know that an address field is unlikely to contain commas).

Comment: would the "date" datatype need to be in enclosed commas too?

Comment: Dates should be 'quoted' as well, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You are not enclosing varchar elements inside quotes, hence address values is read wrongly and error is thrown, enclose last name and address in quotes and insert this would solve the problem

```
INSERT INTO Customer_info (CustomerID, LastName, Username, Address, PhoneNumber, TotalSpent, OrdersCompleted) VALUES (1, 'Mason', 1, '15 Water Rd', 0412345678, 750, 3),(1, 'Mason', 1, '15 Water Rd', 0412345678, 750, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

CREATE TABLE Customer_info (
    CustomerID int,
    LastName varchar(50),
    Username int,
    Address varchar(777),
    PhoneNumber int,
    TotalSpent int,
    OrdersCompleted int
    );

"INSERT INTO Customer_info('CustomerID','LastName','Username','Address','PhoneNumber','TotalSpent','OrdersCompleted')VALUES
    ('1', 'Mason','1','15 Water Rd','0412345678','750','3'), 
    ('2', 'Smith','2','14 Water Rd','0412345679','400','4'),
    ('3', 'Lens','3','1 Water rd','0412345671','700','7'), 
    ('4', 'Marks','4','5 Fire Rd','0412345672','100','1'),
    ('5', 'Barr', '5', '19 Fire Rd','0412345673','500','1'), 
    ('6','Blok','6','21 Fire Rd','0412345674','1000','10'),
    ('7','Pume','7','21 Water Rd','0412345675','1000','2'), 
    ('8','Po','8','77 Earth Rd','0412345676','1000','4'),
    ('9','Adid','9','20 Earth Rd','0412345677','2','200'), 
    ('10', 'Lew', '10','6 Earth Rd','0412345679', '250', '1'),
    ('11','Chia','11','1 Earth Rd','0412345681','150','1'), 
    ('12','Barrett','12','11 Wind Rd','0412345682','450','9'),
    ('13','James','13','9 Wind Rd','0412345683','250','10'), 
    ('14', 'Foop','14','2 Window St','0412345684','200', '10'),
    ('15','Watch','15','8 Window St','0412345685','1200','1'), 
    ('16', 'Irving', '16', '11 Window St', '0412345686', '1400', '2'),
    ('17', 'Jones', '17', '22 Window St', '0412345687', '1600', '2')";

?>
```